# Full Calendar not showing next years events

Tags: fullcalendar

Using Full Calendar I can see Decembers events, however if I click next month to January nothing shows up.

If I change my local date to Jan 2013 the January events show up and I can browse back to December.

Happens for me on the demo site also:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Tested in IE9,FF, Chrome

Has anyone else experienced this or at least confirm you can replicate it and I'm not going mad...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Relax. I don't know about your own cal, but the demo just generates some sample events based on current month,year; check the demo source...